# Replace mysql_result with mysqli_?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

I've have an issue with replacing the `mysql_result` to the correct `mysqli_?` command. It feels like I've tried everything but nothing seems to be working. I'm using it to check if a username is taken for a login-system, like this:

```
   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members WHERE user='{$_POST['user']}'";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
   if (mysql_result($result, 0) > 0) {
     $reg_error[] = 1;
   }
```

I've tried with `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and `mysqli_num_rows` and I've tried to change the whole thing but nothing is working so I'm turning to you guys.

With everything I've tried my script still creates a user even if the username allready exists.

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: Google makes life easier. http://codular.com/php-mysqli. First result when you google 'using php mysqli'. Mysqli is a shift from the ground up, you can't just mix/match mysql_ and mysqli_ functions

Comment: "some undisclosed code doesn't work" is not a question, unless you consider "fix the wrong code" an answer ;-P

Comment: How about error messages ?

Comment: @Eric Do you see any error checking in there? How would the OP be getting an error message?

Comment: Sidenote: You're mixing your functions `mysqli_query` and `mysql_result` --- `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions do not mix. Change your `mysql_result` to `mysqli_result` and it should work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's why I'm trying to replace mysql_* with mysqli_*...

Comment: Ok. Well if you're trying to check if a username exists, you need to use `num_rows` instead. @Bondenn

Comment: I can post something below with something I use that works, if you're interested.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well I've tried replacing `mysql_result` with `mysqli_num_rows` and still the same problem, I'm a beginner so I don't know which other way to use `num_rows` in this part of my code. Yes you can very much post something works for you, because I have ran out of options.

Comment: I posted it below. @Bondenn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use to check if a username exists.

```
$user= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `user`='$user'");

if ($result->num_rows)
  {
echo "ID exist!";
} 
  else
   {
     echo "ID doesnt exist!"
   }
```

**and/or:**

```
$user= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `user`='".$user."'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

    echo "email already exists";
}else{

// do something here

}
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. And do note that `$con` must be used as a parameter with `mysqli_real_escape_string`. It wasn't needed in the `mysql_` version, another reason why using `mysql_*` functions are not safe to use. @Bondenn Cheers

Comment: Added note: Using backticks around table names and columns are better, from what you can see in the code. Follow that structure for future use, although PDO is the next step up. @Bondenn

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Then check the value in $row

Comment: How about adding some error checking? Since handing $result to mysqli_fetch_array() with a bad query will either fail silently like the original code, or throw a PHP fatal error.

Comment: Error checking can be done by  -   if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ';
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $sql;
    die($message);
}

Comment: I know how its done, I'm recommending that if you are going to help solve problems, don't give solutions that include problems.